# How to know which key was used for SOAP body signature verification

Tags: java, cxf, wss, wss4j, java-ws

Using CXF I came across a problem: **I would like to log the public key used to verify the signature provided on the SOAP request.** Initially, I thought about extending the `org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider`, but that allows me to check which keys are effectively loaded, but not which one was successfully used on each request.